# Hyper-V: How to recognize newly added LAN card?

Tags: hyper-v, drivers, hyper-v-server-2012

Yesterday I've installed Hyper-V 2012 and I've forgotten to plug Intel LAN card. Hyper-V has detected built-in Atheros LAN device. Now how can I install the external LAN card automatically? Should I use **pnputil** and driver CD?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is. Can you please be more specific ?

Comment: Can Hyper-V 2012 recognize & install the newly added device drivers automatically where installation already done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use pnputil.  Specifically:

pnputil -i -a drivername.inf

This will bring your NIC on line.  Then you'll want to create a virtual switch on top of it.

You also could have installed the drivers off-line with dism.exe, if you wanted to inject the driver into the Hyper-V image before installing it on a machine.

Comment: Probably Hyper-V installation could detect & recognize Intel Lan card. Next time I'll plug it then install Hyper-V.

Comment: Plus the cable should be plugged to be listed, IMHO.